# How it works when I use Play Asset Delivery without any settings?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile

I'm using Unity 2021.3.14 to create an Android mobile game. I looked up this document on [Play Asset Delivery](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/Manual/play-asset-delivery.html) because the game is over 150mb.

There was a sentence like this.

```
Generated asset packs

Asset packs have download size limits. 
To account for this, Unity changes how it generates asset packs depending on the size of your additional assets:

If the additional assets take less than 1GB of storage,
Unity packs everything into a single asset pack with the install-time delivery mode.
If you do not create any custom asset packs,
this means that the device downloads the asset pack as part of the application installation and,
when the user first launches the application,
all assets are available.
```

Could you check if the following is correct based on what I understood?

1. If an app of less than 1GB and build with `Play Asset Delivery` without configuration, it operates in `install-time` mode and is downloaded together when the user first runs the application.
2. After the installation is completed in the above manner, can I use them without additional code that connects resources inside the game?

The above question may be awkward because I am not familiar with English. I apologize in advance for that. Thank you for reading the question and have a nice day.